# CGRect and CGSize Extensions from Swift Not Visible in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, extension-methods, bridging-header

I have some extensions in Swift on some core graphics structures, namely CGSize and CGRect, here's what the CGSize one looks like....

```
enum Orientation {
        case Portrait
        case Landscape
        case Square
    }


extension CGSize {

    /// Based on the size's dimensions, what orientation is it
    var orientation: Orientation {

        if width > height {
            return .Landscape
        } else if height > width {
            return .Portrait
        } else {
            return .Square
        }
    }

}
```

I need to use these in an Objective-C class. I've imported the Swift header into this class, and other extensions from Swift I've written are working in this class. However, these two aren't visible. I'm guessing it's because these aren't extensions on classes. Is there a way I can get these to work with my Objective-C code?

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's not possible since `Orientation` and `CGSize` are not classes. `Orientation` is an `enum` and `CGSize` is a `struct`.

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53) says, you cannot use in Objective-C these swift features: `Enumerations defined in Swift without Int raw value type` and `Structures defined in Swift`.